# CoreData: Fetch request does not fetch last inserted record? Or how to force refreshing a fetch request

Tags: ios, core-data, uiviewcontroller, core-plot

I asked this question before already, but never got a good answer, so I ask it again, re-phrased, and hope the problem becomes more clear:

I have a tab bar controller A, embedded in a navigation controller. 
The first tab contains a table view Controller B, and the second tab contains a view controller C with a core plot.
The navigation bar has a  + bar button, which modally segues a view controller D, where the user adds a new object/record to core data.

The table view controller D uses a NSFetchedResultsController as its data source, so when the user returns from controller D, the newly created object is displayed in the table view.

However if the user taps the + bar button on the second tab, and creates a new object/record in the modally segued view controller D, and then returns to the second tab, the core plot graph is not updated. I investigated, and found that the fetch request, which supplies the data for the core plot is not updated/executed again.

So, how can I force the fetch request to be executed again?

The code at the end of my 'done' method in view controller D:

```
MRBMITabBarController *tabController = (MRBMITabBarController *) self.delegate;
NSArray *controllers = tabController.viewControllers;
MRBMIKurveViewController *kurveController = (MRBMIKurveViewController *) [controllers objectAtIndex:1];
kurveController.bmisForPlot = nil;
kurveController.bmisForPlot = [[kurveController fetchBmisForPlot] copy];
[kurveController.graph reloadData];
[kurveController.boundLinePlot reloadData];

[self.delegate dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

But this does not refresh the plot in view controller C, however the table view in table view controller D is refreshed.

Note: MRBMIKurveViewController is view controller C.

Answer (score 0):

call:

```
NSError *err = nil;
[managedObjectContext save:&err];
```

after you did change date

call your reload data methods in `viewViewAppear` method of controller

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution:

```
MRBMITabBarController *tabController = (MRBMITabBarController *) self.delegate;
NSArray *controllers = tabController.viewControllers;
MRBMIKurveViewController *kurveController = (MRBMIKurveViewController *) [controllers objectAtIndex:1];

kurveController.bmisForPlot = [[kurveController fetchBmisForPlot] copy];
kurveController.dataForPlot = [kurveController testData3];
[kurveController.boundLinePlot reloadData];

[self.delegate dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Basically I call all methods (via delegate) which are involved in creating the data for the plot inside the "done" method of view controller D before dismissing view controller D

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a separate `fetchedResultsController` on the the core plot view (C) and use this as the data source for the plot.  Not sure how the plot works so you may have to call `reloadData` on it.  You may only need to implement the one fetchedResultsController delegate method `controllerDidChangeContent` to call 'reloadData'.

This way your views are totally independent of each other, the one does not even need to know if the other one exists.  Your way D has to know intimate details of C.  Now you could have a background thread updating the data and your plot will update itself.